# How to add item to generic list through ModelItem.Properties class?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, generics

I'm trying to add new item to generic list. In my XAML application I have 2 text boxes and I have bound to properties.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ModelItem.ReplaceThis, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ModelItem.ReplaceWithThat, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
```

on button click I want to add values of two fields to generic list that will be displayed in ListBox that bound to Generic List Property

```
<Button Name ="btnReplaceAdd" Content="Add" Width="50" Click="btnReplaceAdd_Click"></Button>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ModelItem.ReplaceItems, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

in the code behind to access properties I have the following code.

```
private void btnReplaceAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var _with = this.ModelItem.Properties["ReplaceThis"].Value;
    var _what = this.ModelItem.Properties["ReplaceWithThat"].Value;

    var foo = new List<RenameReplace>();        
    var bar = new RenameReplace() { Rwht = _what.ToString(), Rwth = _with.ToString() };
    foo.Add(bar);

    this.ModelItem.Properties["ReplaceItems"].SetValue(foo);
    this.ModelItem.Properties["ReplaceThis"].SetValue("");
    this.ModelItem.Properties["ReplaceWithThat"].SetValue("");
}
```

once execution of method finishes instead of seeing the value of that I passed I see `MyProject.RenameReplace` inside list box.

Is my problem with the way I'm binding XAML ListBox to generic property or in the way that I'm adding items to generic list?

Comment: What is the data type of `ModelItem.ReplaceItems`? Is it `List<ReplaceItems>`? Then you need to set either the `DisplayMemberPath` property or the `ItemTemplate` property of the `ListBox` control.

Comment: Yes `ReplaceItems` property is of type `List<RenameReplace>`

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve the issue thanks to comments from @fmunkert who pointed to using `ItemTemplate`

had to replace next 4 lines in the code behind

```
var foo = new List<RenameReplace>();        
var bar = new RenameReplace() { Rwht = _what.ToString(), Rwth = _with.ToString() };
foo.Add(bar);
this.ModelItem.Properties["ReplaceItems"].SetValue(foo);
```

with this

```
var bar = new RenameReplace() { Rwht = _what, Rwth = _with };
this.ModelItem.Properties["ReplaceItems"].Collection.Add(bar);
```

now on XAML had to change

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ModelItem.ReplaceItems, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

to this in order to be able to display two items side by side.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ModelItem.ReplaceItems, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=ModelItem.Rwht}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=ModelItem.Rwth}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```